# Content database "Version" in table != (get-spfarm).buildversion

Tags: central-administration, administration, configuration, content-database, version

How is this possible?[image]

The Content database with the version `15.0.4719` was generated with this server, of version `4569`.

I only noticed it because I tried taking a backup and mounting it to another server with exactly the same setup. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Edit: Maybe this is the problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you having windows updates enabled on the servers? If so, some SharePoint updates may have been installed automatically but no PSConfig has be ran to "upgrade" the farm completely

Comment: Ok. I'm running `psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -wait`, let's see what happens

Answer (score 1):

looks like their is missing updates or missing PSconfig wizard.from the versions numbers, one farm is on Service Pack 1 and one is on May 2015 CU.

I think one farm get the updates and other is still behind. You have to apply same update on 2nd farm.

Check more about version numbers here: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346